# Mercurial run a hook on the server when "no changes found" by a client

Tags: mercurial

Is there a hack or a way out to run a hook on the server whenever a client pushes or pulls and gets "no changes found". I want to be able to run a script on a client's pull irrespective of whether the repository has changed or not.

Currently it is easily possible to use the standard hooks (`pretxnchangegroup`, `changegroup`, etc.) for all cases but they do not get triggered when there is no change.

Comment: A hook isn't going to be able to do what you're (now) asking.  I've revised the question to reflect that you want server-side execution when a client pushes or pulls and gets no changes, which you've said in my original, deleted answer.

Comment: Why do you want to run something serverside on no-ops?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing @Macke.

Comment: this is same as why does google count the clicks on each of their links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hook wont' be able to do what you're looking for.  The hooks that run on the server side are all triggered by the arrival of things (changesets or pushkeys).  There's no server-side hook for *nothing-arrived* nor for commands that never send things (`incoming`, `outgoing`, etc.).

One long shot I tried **that didn't work** was using a `post-serve` hook.  When a client connects to a remote repository over ssh it's really running `hg serve` on that client, so I was hoping as `post-serve` hook would be executed at the end of a ssh session, but no such luck (indeed that hook likely doesn't exist at all).

Fortunately there are some other hackier-options than hooks.  For repositories you access over ssh you can alter the `.ssh/authorized-keys` file to force the execution of some command:

```
command="/home/me/hg_and_somethingelse.sh" ssh-rsa AAAA....
```

then in `/home/me/hg_and_something_else.sh` you'd have:

```
#!/bin/bash
hg $@
echo ANY COMMAND FROM HERE ONWARD IS RUN FOR EVERY PUSH, PULL, CLONE, etc.
```

Similar for http-served repos you'd just tack whatever you want at the end of [the wsgi file you're using](http://www.selenic.com/repo/hg-stable/file/692cbda1eb50/contrib/hgweb.wsgi).

As a caveat there are a lot of tools (IDEs for example) that check for changes often, so your script is going to be run more frequently than you're imagining.

Comment: Good point Ry4an , But this will also run when you login using ssh? Secondly it will not be able distinguish push & pull. or is there a way around?

Comment: With `command=` in place you can't login and get a shell -- use separate key for the repo (separate from your login key).  The scripts arguments will have the full command line in there, so you can check for `push`, `pull` or any other command that hits the server (`$2` probabaly...)

Comment: I think this is probably one of the simpler options to go about it without going into any deep coding . thanks.